# How to find the change in x required to deintersect two circles given radius and position

Tags: geometry, circles

I have two circles, `A` and `B`; circle `A'` is found by translating `A` along the x-axis until it is tangent with circle `B`.

`A` has a radius of `r1` and a position of `(x1,y1)`
`B` has a radius of `r2` and a position of `(x2,y2)`

How can I find the change in x required to separate the two circles to a point of tangency?

[Problem Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btsTS.png)

Comment: Do you have any additional information, for example about the relationship of the centres of the circles? I'm asking because in general, there can be 0, 1 or 2 solutions. If the circles are tangent to each other, then
$$
(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 = (r_1+r_2)^2
$$
The simplest way of finding a solution is solving this for $x_1$ and comparing the obtained value with the initial location of the first circle.

Comment: Let $A'(x_1+\Delta x,y_1)$. Then solve $(x_2-(x_1+\Delta x))^2+(y_2-y_1)^2=(r_1+r_2)^2$ with respect to $\Delta x$. It's quadratic equation, therefore it generally has two solutions, for your picture one solution corresponds to right translation ($\Delta x > 0$), other — to left translation ($\Delta x < 0$).

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu this works great, thanks!